# wxPython - wxHtmlWindow, can the scrollbar be kept at the veyr bottom at all times?

Tags: python, wxpython, wxhtmlwindow

I am working on a chatroom client and am using an HTML window to process things like images and html tags and formatting. I am having trouble finding out how to make the scrollbar stay at the bottom as messages are added to the window (every message sends the bar to the top)

would anyone know how I would go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you add a new message, you can call `Scroll` on your `htmlWindow` to set its `scrollBar`  position to the end.

```
yourHtmlWindow.Scroll(-1, self.GetClientSize()[0])
```

If you want your scrollBar to stay at the bottom when the window is resized then you will need to `Bind` to `wx.EVT_SIZE` so that you can call `Scroll` on resize.

```
def onSize(self, event):
    event.Skip()
    wx.CallAfter(yourHtmlWindow.Scroll, -1, self.GetClientSize()[0])
```